# Script to the active Sheet on Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this script for google sheet

```
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
 spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Base'), true);
 spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(5, 5, 97, 2).activate();
 spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('1'), true);
 spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(-99, 0).activate();
 spreadsheet.getRange('Base!F6:G102').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
```

but I want it to run on the active sheet, so not with getSheetByName.
I did the same macro in VBA and this is what I want it to look like but on google sheet.

```
Sheets("Base").Range("A6:E102").Copy Destination:=Range("A5")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `getSheetByName`, use `getActiveSheet`:

```
var activeSheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
```

And assign it to a variable for easy access.

#### Code:

```
function copyData() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var baseSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Base");
  var activeSheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  baseSheet.getRange("A6:E102").copyTo(activeSheet.getRange("A5"));
}

function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Custom Menu')
    .addItem('Copy A6:E102 of "Base" sheet to A5 of current sheet', 'copyData')
    .addToUi();
}
```

#### Sample data:

[image: sample]

#### Output:

[image: output]

#### Note:

- I have added a custom menu for easy access. You just need to refresh the tab once the script has been saved for the custom menu to show.
- Go to the desired sheet and click the custom menu to paste the values there.

#### Reference:

- [getActiveSheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getactivesheet)
- [copyTo](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination)
- [Menu](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus)

Comment: So this line spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('1'), true); Should look like this  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet..getActiveSheet(), true); ?

Comment: hi @TTiM3R, `setActiveSheet` makes a specific sheet active. You do not need to use it on `getActiveSheet` since it just simply returns the active sheet. It's like setting the active sheet as active sheet so it is useless. Better explain the script behavior of that excel macro instead or at least show what it does in terms of sample data and output for me to understand what you want to do better. Simple line showing that without any explanation will most likely yield you vague answers.

Comment: hi @NaziA I want todo exactly what the VBA line does but on google Sheet. So select a range of cells from the Base sheet and paste it to my active sheet but in a diffrent cell range (same size though).

Comment: Hi @TTiM3R, i have modified my answer. See updated answer above. Added a custom menu for easy access of the function created.

Comment: @TTiM3R, did the answer above answer your question?

Comment: Yes thanks, it works perfectly. I wanted to know if you can assign a key shortcut (CTRL+  SHIFT + ALT + NUMBER) from the script editor or you have to record a blank macro assign a shortcut to it and then edit the macro you created.

Comment: Yes you can @TTiM3R. Firstly, you have to create your function. For this, you only need the `copyData` function (You can remove the other function `onOpen`). Next, once it is saved, Go to Sheets UI and go to `Macros` and choose `Import Macro`. Click `Add Function` for `copyData`. Go back to `Macros` and choose `Manage Macros` and assign the key shortcut for the `copyData` macro that was added.